# Unity 3D Waypoint Icon Movement Issue on Y-axis

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm facing issues with the movement of a waypoint icon in Unity 3D, specifically on the y-axis. The icon behaves unexpectedly when the camera is rotated, causing jitters and incorrect positioning. I've attempted various adjustments, including modifications to the MoveToScreenEdge function, without success.

The waypoint icon should smoothly transition along the screen edge without jittering or unexpected movements, even when the object is behind the camera.

Below is the script with the issue

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class WayPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject waypointCanvas; // Assign the canvas in the inspector
    public Sprite icon; // Assign the icon sprite in the inspector

    private Image waypointIcon;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Find the Image component on the existing canvas
        waypointIcon = waypointCanvas.GetComponentInChildren<Image>();

        if (waypointIcon == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No Image component found on the canvas. Make sure you have an Image component as a child of the canvas.");
        }
        else
        {
            // Set the icon sprite
            waypointIcon.sprite = icon;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Update the position of the waypoint icon
        UpdateWaypointPosition();
    }

    private void UpdateWaypointPosition()
    {
        if (waypointIcon != null && Camera.main != null)
        {
            // Get the screen position of the target object
            Vector3 screenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

            // Check if the object is on-screen
            if (screenPos.z > 0 && IsOnScreen(screenPos))
            {
                // Set the icon's position on the canvas to match the screen position
                waypointIcon.rectTransform.position = screenPos;
            }
            else
            {
                // Move the icon to the screen edge if the object is off-screen
                MoveToScreenEdge(screenPos);
            }
        }
    }

    private bool IsOnScreen(Vector3 screenPos)
    {
        return screenPos.x > 0 && screenPos.x < Screen.width && screenPos.y > 0 && screenPos.y < Screen.height;
    }

    private void MoveToScreenEdge(Vector3 screenPos)
    {
        RectTransform canvasRect = waypointCanvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

        // Calculate the normalized screen coordinates
        Vector2 normalizedScreenPos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(screenPos);

        // Get the direction from the camera to the target object
        Vector3 dirToTarget = (transform.position - Camera.main.transform.position).normalized;

        // Calculate the dot product to check if the object is behind the camera
        float dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(dirToTarget, Camera.main.transform.forward);

        // Determine the quadrant of the screen based on the dot product
        bool isLeft = normalizedScreenPos.x < 0.5f;
        bool isTop = normalizedScreenPos.y > 0.5f;

        // Set the icon's anchored position on the canvas based on the dot product and normalized coordinates
        Vector2 canvasEdgePos;

        if (dotProduct > 0.0f)
        {
            // If the object is not behind, place the icon on the edge
            canvasEdgePos = new Vector2(
                Mathf.Lerp(-canvasRect.sizeDelta.x / 2f, canvasRect.sizeDelta.x / 2f, normalizedScreenPos.x),
                Mathf.Lerp(-canvasRect.sizeDelta.y / 2f, canvasRect.sizeDelta.y / 2f, normalizedScreenPos.y)
            );
        }
        else
        {
            // If the object is behind, smoothly transition the icon along the inverted edge
            float offsetY = Mathf.Lerp(0f, isTop ? canvasRect.sizeDelta.y / 2f : -canvasRect.sizeDelta.y / 2f, normalizedScreenPos.y);

            canvasEdgePos = new Vector2(
                isLeft ? canvasRect.sizeDelta.x / 2f : -canvasRect.sizeDelta.x / 2f,
                offsetY
            );
        }

        // Apply the position to the icon
        waypointIcon.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = canvasEdgePos;
    }
}
```